# How to structure a database to speed up the retrieval of items

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

**Background:**

I have a SQLite database. The database has two tables: keys and elements.

```
CREATE TABLE keys (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, key TEXT)
CREATE TABLE elements (key_id INTEGER, element TEXT)
```

**Example keys:**

- (1, Some key)
- (2, Other key)

**Example elements:**

- (1, Frist word)
- (1, Second word)
- (1, Third word)
- (2, First word)
- (2, Second word)

**Count:**

- keys: 2.600.000
- elements: 3.800.000

I generate text based on this database:

```
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT id 
    FROM keys
    WHERE key = ?
""", (key,))
key_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]

cursor.execute("""
    SELECT element
    FROM elements
    WHERE key_id = ?
""", (key_id,))
elements = cursor.fetchall()
word = "".join(random.choice(elements))
```

This code is executed 10-20 times. But it's so slow. Generation can take 20-30 seconds.

**Questions:**

1. How do i structure a database in order to speed up the generation?
2. What is the best way to store elements? Each element in a own row with key_id and value? Or one row with key_id and value contain all elements?

Comment: I found Database Design for Mere Mortals: A Hands-on Guide to Relational Database Design to be a great resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To speed up the performance of the first query, you can add an index to the `key` column.  Similarly, to speed up the second query, you could add an index on `key_id`:

```
CREATE INDEX key_idx ON keys (key);
CREATE INDEX elmt_idx ON element (key_id);
```

This would help the `WHERE` clause in the two queries to find the record or records you want to return.

As for your second question, your current design, with each key and value in a separate row, is probably the best way to go here.  For one thing, it makes finding a given value much easier.  If you were to store the values as comma-separated data, for example, it would be much more difficult to sift out a value.  And you would not be able to take advantage of any index.

Comment: Awesome! Now generation takes about 1-2 seconds. But this slowed the creation of a database, yes? Also the size increased by 1.5.

Comment: @Immersion Yes, an index takes up space, which may be a drawback, especially if the database resides on a mobile device where space is very precious and limited.  For the increase in database creation time, is that really a big deal for you?  If it only happens once, I would imagine it not being as big an issue as space or speed of the query.